# iOS send file to printer using bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, printing, bluetooth, external-accessory

I'm currently developing an iOS app to directly print with my HP Sprocket printer but I'm stuck with the bluetooth data I have to send to the printer.

After reading some forum I made some test and it's possible to print by sending a jpeg (or png) file directly to the printer using bluetooth.
I tested with a Windows 10 computer and using `Send file` option in bluetooth icon in task bar.

I concluded that it must exist a standard to send a file with bluetooth.

My phone and my app correctly pair with the printer but when I send the encoded jpeg file to the printer nothing happens (no printing, no error code, no bluetooth return)...

I encode my image with:

```swift
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myUIImage, 1.0)
```

And send it using iOS [ExternalAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) framework:

```swift
imageData.withUnsafeBytes { outputStream.write($0, maxLength: imageData.count) }
```

Do I have to send a specific code before or with image data to tell the printer that this message is a file?

Has anyone developed a custom app for this printer (or a similar one)?

**NOTE:**
I use [ExternalAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory) because this printer (HP Sprocket) doesn't support AirPrint and use bluetooth 3.0 (no Low Energy) with the Apple MFi program.

Comment: Which printer you are using?

Comment: It's an HP Sprocket and there is no SDK or developer infos for this printer

Comment: https://medium.com/@punitteraiya234/print-from-your-ios-app-32323b060e0d check this blog

Comment: I already tried AirPrint but this printer is not compatible, it use bluetooth with Apple MFi (bluetooth 3.0 without Low Energy)

Comment: @TristanPct did you manage to create the app? I'm investigating if I can do it but I'm a bit lost